# Jump to previous to previous segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboardsegue

I have many view controllers and i want to jump last to last view controller on click event of button.

Give me example by :-

- using segue
- using code

Also, If I do something at button action and after that performing operation it should jump to previous to previous view. How I can solve this?

Comment: please provide more information with example line of code.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by this single line of code

```
 [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

This will help.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If last to last view controller is not the root view controller, then you will need to fetch the array of view controllers first then check class type of each of its object and when it match it with your desired one then move to that.

```
    NSArray *arrayViewController=[self.navigationController viewControllers];
for (UIViewController *childView in arrayViewController) {
    if ([childView isKindOfClass:[HomeScreenViewController class]]) {
        HomeScreenViewController *viewDesired=(HomeScreenViewController *)childView;
        [self.navigationController popToViewController:viewDesired animated:YES];
    }
}
```